# how do I upload multiple images to my server?

Tags: php, reactjs

I need to retrieve images from my react and send them to my php controller, then store them in a folder on my server. Each time I upload several images, only the last uploaded image is saved in my folder, but I want them all to be saved.

here's the form

```
<form className="formPost" onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">                        
        <form className="formPost" onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
```

here's the function for fetch my controller :

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        const date = new Date();
        const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit'
        });
        const hour = date.getHours();
        const min = date.getMinutes();
        const tokenUser = localStorage.getItem("token");

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('post', inputStr);
        formData.append('timestamp', `${formattedDate} ${hour}:${min}`);
        formData.append('gif', imgGif);
        formData.append('user_id', tokenUser);

        const files = document.getElementById('fileIMG').files;
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append(`img[]`, files[i]);
        }



        fetch('http://localhost:8000/controller/tweetPost.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Erreur réseau: ${response.statusText}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la requête:', error);
            });
    };
```

here's my php controller :

```
<?php
use post\Post;
use user\User;

require_once("../model/post.php");
require_once("../model/user.php");

header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    exit(0);
}

$post = $_POST['post'] ?? '';
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'] ?? '';
$gif = $_POST['gif'] ?? '';
$token = $_POST['user_id'] ?? '';

$userModel = new User();
$userModel->tokenConnexion = json_decode($token);
$user_id = $userModel->findUserWithToken();

$imgPostDir = "../img/post/";
$imgURLs = [];

if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])) {
    if (!is_dir($imgPostDir)) {
        mkdir($imgPostDir, 0777, true);
    }

    $fileCount = count($_FILES['img']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
        $error = $_FILES['img']['error'][$i];
        if ($error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmpName = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $name = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
            $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $validExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
            error_log("Number of files received: " . count($_FILES['img']['name']));
            if (in_array($extension, $validExtensions)) {
                $filename = uniqid("post_", true) . '.' . $extension;                $filePath = $imgPostDir . $filename;

                if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath)) {
                    $imgURLs[] = "http://localhost:8000/img/post/" . $filename;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to loop over my images in order to save them 1 by 1 in the folder, but to no avail.

Comment: So the number of files you log to your error log, what does that actually say?